# How to use CQL_FILTER as URL encoded parameter to compare a field containing numbers

Tags: geoserver, wms, wfs, cql-filter, wildcard

I want to apply the CQL_FILTER parameter as an URL parameter in order to filter a field containing numbers (zip codes) starting with 79 (using 79% Wildcard) for instance.

So I'm using this CQL_FILTER:

```
&CQL_FILTER%3DZIP%20like%20%2779%25%27 (url-encoded)
&CQL_FILTER=ZIP like '79%' (url-decoded)
```

It seems that my CQL_Filter is not working since I get no results. I don't get any error but I also don't get the corresponding features starting with 79 zipcode.

Is the like operator in CQL_Filters applicable to numbers?

Comment: No clue, a similar one against topp:states works, e.g., anything with STATE_FIPS starting with 2:
http://demo.geo-solutions.it/geoserver/topp/wms?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetMap&FORMAT=image%2Fpng&TRANSPARENT=true&STYLES&LAYERS=topp%3Astates&CQL_FILTER=STATE_FIPS%20like%20%272%25%27&SRS=EPSG%3A4326&WIDTH=768&HEIGHT=330&BBOX=-129.375%2C23.203125%2C-61.875%2C52.20703125

Comment: So, what was the problem? Better share it in an answer for others that might stumble in the same issue.

Comment: I I just used &CQL_FILTER=ZIP like '79%25'

Comment: The `=` sign shoud not be encoded as it is not part of the parameter but it is the name/value separator.   `&CQL_FILTER=ZIP%20like%20%2779%25%27` will work. The demo URL relies on the browser to encode the space characters, which is not rock solid so your proposed solution is the proper one.